# To show Mobile Bookmarks of Chrome in Desktop?

Tags: chrome-for-android, app-widgets, bookmarks

I would like show my bookmarks in my Screen because some webpages work better than any application.
It would be also create an application-like-button for a webpage if possible.

Possible through some widget. 
However, I did not find any existing widget.

How can you create an-application-like button for a webpage?

How can you show your mobile bookmarks of Chrome in your desktop?

Comment: There should be a bookmarks widget pre-installed with your device. Have you checked that in your app drawer?

Comment: By Desktop do you mean home screen of mobile or literally the Desktop used to refer to Windows' PC?

Comment: @Firelord Yes, by desktop, I mean the home screen of mobile.

Comment: There is further clarification I need: 1)  Chrome at the moment can export a webpage link as an icon to home screen. Is it not enough for you?  2) That app shortcut/widget that you've asked for: do you want a single shortcut which would open a list of bookmarks or do you want individual shortcuts for each of the bookmarked website?

Comment: @Firelord I do not know what is the optimum result. I think both would be handy, but the central thing should the control system how you manage both those views. For instance, having icons to some webpage -tools on the mobile desktop, while having a capability to scroll-like icon-menu which allows to see fast on the mobile desktop some linked sites. Those views and items should then be able to be managed on the PC application etc on a webpage.

Comment: @Masi, I thought to understand what you're asking for – until you put that last sentence in your last comment. What PC application are you talking about? Chrome on your PC cannot create desktop elements on the Android device, or manage them. That's the domain of the homescreen app.

Comment: @Izzy I just spoke about future and extensibility. It would good if you could better combine the views of the Mobile Desktop and Desktop PC. I think the integration of these systems must include control tools about the views, etc. However, just another idea which can be accepted-rejected after many iterations when the basics of the system has been formulated.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to live display an actual webpage on screen/page x of your device like live desktop from windows 98?

Comment: No. I am not asking that.

Comment: So you're effectively asking for an application to manage your bookmarks cross-device, with an Android part that integrates with your browser and can be controlled from your PC. No such thing natively, obviously – and asking for an app/software for X is off-topic here (though answers might offer such as solutions). I've never heard of such a combination either – and thus I'm afraid your question is unlikely to receive working answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution to the task. Use Google Keep which integrates nicely to your Internet browsers. During the time of asking the question, I did not know about Google Keep. You get there nice frontend where you can easily add a link and there many links such that the presentation of many links is also nice with the preview of their contents.